# Prove convergence and find limit of recursive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Letting $a_{1}=2$ I have a recursive sequence defined as follows:
$$ a_{n+1} = \frac{a_{n}}{2} + \frac{5}{a_{n}} \ \  \forall n \geq1$$

How can I prove that the sequence {$a_{n}$} converges and also find the limit of this sequence? I plugged in first few terms and get something like:

2,

3.5,

3.179,

3.162,

3.162,

...

The textbook example showed an example of a recursive sequence that was monotone, but this sequence I have here does not appear as such. However, this sequence looks like a Cauchy sequence though. I am completely lost and not sure how to proceed. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove the following sequence is a Cauchy Sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005061/prove-the-following-sequence-is-a-cauchy-sequence) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24a_%7Bn%2B1%7D%20%3D%20%5Cfrac%7Ba_%7Bn%7D%7D%7B2%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B5%7D%7Ba_%7Bn%7D%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: Your calculation for $a_3$ is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By induction we see that $a_n>0$ and since $$a_{n+1}-\sqrt{10}=\frac{(a_n-\sqrt{10})^2}{2a_n}\geq0,$$ by induction we obtain $$a_n>\sqrt{10}$$ for all $n\geq2.$

In another hand, $$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{5}{a_n}-\frac{a_n}{2}=\frac{(\sqrt{10}-a_n)(\sqrt{10}+a_n)}{2a_n}<0,$$ for all $n\geq2,$ which gives that $a$ decreases.

Id est, there is $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n$ and let this limit is equal to $a$.

We obtain $$a=\frac{5}{a}+\frac{a}{2},$$ which gives $a=\sqrt{10}.$

Comment: A possible duplicate was pointed out 2 hours ago ... your solution is essentially https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1005120.